# android opengl textures loaded in background thread get overwritten

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, locking

i am loading textures in a background thread and then send the Bitmap to the GL thread (via GLSurfaceView.queueEvent(...)) to upload it to the graphics card. to prevent garbage collection after each image load i reuse one Bitmap with power of two dimensions for sending a texture to open gl.

and that is the problem, this bitmap gets overwritten sometimes, as the worker thread and GL thread are fighting each other. as i understand it, it is impossible to acquire a lock in one thread (worker) and unlock it in another thread (GL). so i came with a solution like this (my thread is a HandlerThread):

```
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch(msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_FROM_MAIN_THREAD:
            m_Lock.lock();
            loadTextureFromAssets(msg.obj.toString(), msg.arg1);
            break;

        case MESSAGE_FROM_GL_THREAD:
            m_Lock.unlock();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

were m_Lock is a ReentrantLock. but this still does not work and sometimes a texture is repeated (or partially overwritten by the next one). it looks like the unlocks are in LIFO order...

any ideas except creating a new Bitmap for each loaded texture and causing GC? ...it could be solved for almost all cases with having two Bitmaps for loading textures and switching between them, but this is not 100% correct. i'd like to solve this with proper threads synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so after more then a day i figured this out. i used a Semaphore initially set to 1 and acquire it before `LoadTextureFromAssets(...)` and release it at the end of a `Runnable` sent to GL to upload the texture:

```
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch(msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_FROM_MAIN_THREAD:
            try {
                m_Semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            loadTextureFromAssets(msg.obj.toString(), msg.arg1);

            break;

        case MESSAGE_FROM_GL_THREAD:
            // not needed for now
            break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

and int the upload method:

```
// load the image from assests and then...
m_GLSurface.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TexId);

                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);

                if (gl instanceof GL11) {
                    // GL 1.1 has auto mip-map generation
                    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
                    gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL11.GL_TRUE);
                }

                GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, m_TexBitmap, 0);

                m_Semaphore.release();
            }
    });
```

is this a 100% correct way?

Comment: This is not 100% correct since an exception could occur and your semaphore might never be released. Therefore you must make sure you call it in a finally-block.

Comment: Also your try { ... } code is wrong. You should either retry acquiring the semaphore or abort completely. But right now you interrupt only the acquisition of the semaphore and not the actual texture loading.